# JavaScript event doesn't work in IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

It seems like IE8 ignores my click event! It should add a new row when I press a "+" button and remove it on "-".  I'm new to WEB Development but I can't see any others issues. I test it and it works fine with IE10, IE9 but doesn't work with IE8!!! Could you help me to sort this problem!

My HTML code:

```
<table id="sysAffectedTable2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th><span class="locationName">Location Name</span></th>
            <th>Subnet (Optional)</th>
            <th>Add</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="locationName1" value="" name="locationName1"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="subnet1" value="" name="subnet1"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" style="width: 40px" id="addDiskButton2" value="  +  " onclick="insertRow2()"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" style="width: 40px" id="delDiskButton2" value="  -  " onclick="deleteRow2(this)"/></td>    
        </tr>
    </tbody>        
    </table>
```

My javaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var maxRow2=1;


    var table2 = document.getElementById('sysAffectedTable2'), tbody2 = table2
            .getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0], clone2 = tbody2.rows[0]
            .cloneNode(true);

    function deleteRow2(el) {
        var i = el.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;

        if (i != 1) {
            table2.deleteRow(i);
            while (table2.rows[i]) {
                updateRow2(table2.rows[i], i, false);
                i++;
            }
            maxRow2--;
        } else if (i == 1) {
            table2.deleteRow(i + 1);
            while (table2.rows[i + 1]) {
                updateRow2(table2.rows[i + 1], i + 1, false);
                i++;
            }
            maxRow2--;
        }
    }

    function insertRow2() {
        if (maxRow2 < 32) {
            var new_row = updateRow2(clone2.cloneNode(true),
                    ++tbody2.rows.length, true);
            tbody2.appendChild(new_row);
            maxRow2++;
        }
    }

    function updateRow2(row2, a2, reset2) {
        row2.cells[0].innerHTML = a2;

        var inp1 = row2.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        var inp2 = row2.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

        inp1.name = 'locationName' + a2;
        inp1.id = 'locationName' + a2;
        inp2.name = 'subnet' + a2;
        inp2.id = 'subnet' + a2;

        if (reset2) {
            inp1.value = inp2.value = '';
        }
        return row2;
    }
</script>
```

You can see it in live [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yHANj/1/) - http://jsfiddle.net/yHANj/1/

Please could you help me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Updated the tags for your question, since the JavaScript code you posted doesn't use jQuery anywhere.

Comment: Why in heaven's name are you using jQuery v1.4.2? It was replaced with a newer version between two and three *years* ago.

Comment: @Blazemonger: But if you remove jQuery entirely from the question, people won't know it's okay to rely on jQuery in their answers, which is not good. (This is only relevant if you remove it from the title and text as well...)

Comment: Use the console! `SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action 
show, line 72 character 5` `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An error is being encountered on this line: `++tbody2.rows.length`

Apparently IE8's javascript engine treats this differently than other browsers, but it doesn't make sense to be able to change the `length` property for the number of rows of the table in *any* browser. If you wanted to change the number of rows in a table, you'd do so by inserting a new DOM element (which you're doing with the `.appendChild()` call).

Change it to `tbody2.rows.length + 1` instead of trying to increment the `length` property directly.

EDIT: Indeed, if you try to increment `length` other browsers, the statement appears to be simply ignored. IE8 throws an exception instead of ignoring it.

Comment: Hi David, so I tested my webisite with IE8 its working perfect but I'm testing it with IE7 and its seems that I've got the same problem - if you press on the "+" or "-" nothing happens :( Could you help me please ;) Thanks mate!

Comment: You're running into a problem with cloning nodes in IE7 described here: http://jehiah.cz/a/rows-and-cells-in-ie-when-using-clonenode. I reworked your fiddle so that it functions in IE7: http://jsfiddle.net/dmillz/spYTv/. If this is helpful, feel free to upvote the previously accepted answer :-)